# Simple Rails user messaging system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, database-relations

I need to implement very simple messaging system between 2 users, and the only requirement is to keep every conversation between 2 users separate.
I wonder whether it's possible and reasonable to use only one model `Message(sender_id, recipient_id )` to achieve the goal.

Suppose, I want to get index of all conversations.

- Join on `user.id = recipient_id` and `user.id = sender_id`  to get all messages associated with specific user
- Order results by `id` of opposed participants(whether it is `sender_id` or `recipient_id`) to form groups of messages - chatboxes. This is I think the most difficult step, since opposed user might be a sender or a receiver in one conversation.
- Further order results inside each group by date of creation to show messages in their original order. Each group denotes a different conversation.

I tried `Mailboxer` gem, but it seems to be overkill for this case.
I also think of a different solution based on introduction of new `Conversation` entity with one-to-many relation with messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think [simple-private-messages](https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages) will solve your problem. It seems simple and looks exactly like what you are looking for.

Comment: Seems to be good one, but what i'm exactly looking for is the way to group messages that belong to one conversation between 2 people, like   `@user.conversations[0].messages`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no such lightweight implementation of messaging that involves grouping them by `conversation`. The best solution seems to be implementing it from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

You should also give a look at faye server https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails & http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Comment: I'll definitely take a look when the project needs will require real-time interaction.